# Does there exist a way to do small fixed range multiplication efficiently?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Suppose I have an inline function:

```
inline int mul(short x, short y) {
    return (int)x * (int)y;
}
```

Here **y** is in {1,2,...,32}, and **x** is in {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,...,8192}.  Considering **y** is in a very small range, does there exist a way to speed up mul()?

Background: this code is extracted from a scientific computing program written in C/C++, and profiling has shown that the above function consumes over 10% CPU time of the whole program since it is called very frequently. Therefore, I would like to try to figure out a way to speed it up.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is likely that the multiplication is going to get compiled down to a single CPU instruction. As such, no further optimization is likely to happen.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to reduce the number of calls to this instead of reducing the cost of the call itself?

Comment: That's right, but that would be another question.

Comment: Looking at the generated assembly would help, and you can make sure that all calls to the function truly gets inlined, `inline` doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: Changing to: `inline int mul(int x, int y) { return x * y;}` could also help.

Comment: I think we're looking at this too much with a microscope. If we zoom out a bit, you might find opportunities to vectorize the arithmetic, improve locality of reference, etc. Just staring at a simple function which is almost certainly going to be inlined to multiply two ints is going to make it really difficult to optimize -- too little info.

Comment: What processor are you using?

Comment: @chux intel Haswell & Skylake

Comment: 10% is probably not a bottleneck. Also, arithmetic instructions are a bottleneck only in very well tuned applications. Virtually all modern apps are bound by memory accesses. You should really *look towards memory* first. As of arithmetics, you might *vectorize*, *parallelize* or to *improve algorithms* to take less multiplications (i.e. to call `mul` less frequently).

Comment: If profiling shows this is taking 10% of the CPU time, clearly it isn't being inlined at all. Hard to understand why this is a function at all. I would just remove it, or turn it into a macro. Nothing wrong with writing `x*y` in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's SSE4 intrinsics provide the data type `__m128i`, which can hold 4 32-bit values.

> `__m128i _mm_mullo_epi32(__m128i a, __m128i b)`
>
> Packed integer 32-bit multiplication with truncation of upper halves of results.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531409%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can perform 4 multiplications at a time. Since you know that your data range is limited, truncation won't be a problem. You could also use single-precision floating point and the older `mulps` intrinsic.

Besides, it might be a good idea to analyze your program with a profiler like VTune and see if you are suffering from excessive cache misses, aliasing, or alignment problems.